# Как понять фразу из акафиста Покрову Божьей Матери

Tags: значение-слов

Радуйся, тайная и неудобь предвидения все добре ведущая и имже подобает сказующая

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неудобь = невозможное, чудное.

> Радуйся, тайная и неудобь предвидения все добре ведущая и имже
>   подобает сказующая.

Промысел Божий имеет совершенство, — говорится в одном комментарии, — передать Матери немалую часть Своих возможностей среди мира рабов Божиих возвещать тайное вразумление сродное образу жизни. И перефразировать можно так:

*Радуйся, потаённое и чудное наперёд видящая и ясно знающая, и каждого направляющая.*